# Error WCF - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wcf

**HTML Jquery Ajax**
HTML page is running in http://domain2.application.net/index.html.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://domain.service.net/Service.svc/AddUsers",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: dataToSend,
                dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

                success: function (response) {        
                }
            });
```

WCF Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void AddUsers(string name, string email)
{            
    //Add user information to database          
}
```

While calling an AddUser service i got an following error
**Error**

```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://domain.service.net/Service.svc/AddUsers. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://domain2.application.net' is therefore not
> allowed access.
```

Browser header value

```
Request URL:http://domain.service.net/Service.svc/AddUsers
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, accept, access-control-allow-credentials, x-requested-with, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:domain.service.net
Origin:http:http://domain2.application.net
Referer:http:http://domain2.application.net/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: CORS has to be allowed in order for this to work. http://enable-cors.org/ OR you might have to provide authentication credentials to the remote server.

Comment: OK - are you still getting the same error? If so you will need to see if the remote service requires authentication.

Comment: I added global.ascx --- protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
...

Comment: still i'm getting the error...

Comment: @JayBlanchard CAn you guide me to do a remote service authentication.

Comment: Are you following the API of the service provider? They should have documentation on what you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

if you take a look at [here](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2772/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requeste) you will notice that the problem is back-end related so in order to fix this you have to add a couple of helpers to you WCF project and also explicit modify web.config web service endpoint to be

```
<crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
```

A possible solution is place [here at this site](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html).

Hope it helps! good luck CORS for the world!